# Bash script that checks between 2 csv files old and new. To check that in the new file, the line count has content which is x % of the old files?

Tags: bash

As of now how i am writing the script is to count the number of lines for the 2 files.

Then i put it though condition if it is greater than the old.

However, i am not sure how to compare it based on percentage of the old files.

I there a better way to design the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i new=$(< "$(ls -t file name*.csv | head -n 1)" wc -l)
declare -i old=$(< "$(ls -t file name*.csv | head -n 2)" wc -l)

echo $new
echo $old

if [ $new -gt $old ];
then
echo "okay";
else
echo "fail";
```

Comment: What do you mean my percentage? Like use a `diff`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check for x% max diff line, you can count the number of '<' lines in the diff output. Recall the the diff output will look like.

```
+ diff node001.html node002.html
2,3c2,3
< 4
< 7
---
> 2
> 3
```

So that code will look like:

```
old=$(wc -l < file1)
diff1=$(diff file1 file2 | grep -c '^<')
pct=$((diff1*100/(old-1)))
   # Check Percent
if [ "$pct" -gt 60 ] ; then
   ...
fi
```